# Can I cache just the last page visited?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to cache only the last page the client visits in MVC, like a browser does, or do i need to use javascript and use the browser functionality?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Please provide more information

Comment: I want the user to refer back to previous page without having the previous page actually post to server again.

Comment: Are you asking about adding history for AJAX generated content on pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the previous page on the server (output caching), but there's no way to refer to it from the next page.

Would something like cross-page posts work for you? They reconstruct the state of the controls on the previous page, and make them accessible to the current page.

Information from a previous page is normally considered "state" information -- as such, one alternative is to use cookies or Session state to store the information you need to carry over.